# At what age could a man start bringing offerings for sin in ancient Israel to the priest?

Tags: old-testament, atonement

I just want to know if the scriptures or another source specify if little children or young man could offer sacrifices. Or if there was a minimum age for it. Only men? Grown up, men?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, Liz.  Thanks for joining us.  While you wil likely receive an answer to this question here, you might find one faster at our sister site, [judaism.se].

Comment: Exodus 30:14 (KJV) Every one that passeth among them that are numbered, from twenty years old and above, shall give an offering unto the LORD. See also this [informative link](http://www.natewilsonfamily.net/ManhoodAge20.htm).

Comment: This seems to be more of a Jewish question than a Christian one.

Comment: Thank you Nigel J and JBH :) I was unaware of that site! Very helpful, sorry for the inconvenience.